# Access IP camera (rtsp) using OpenCV (C++) in Docker?

Tags: docker, opencv, c++11, video-streaming

I am trying to build a docker image to get the video streams from the IP camera and take each frame for further processing using:

Ubuntu 18.04
OpenCV 4.1
C++ 11
Docker

I have tried to use the webcam on the laptop using the following docker command and it works:

```
docker run -i -t --device /dev/video0 <docker image> /bin/bash
```

C++ code:

```
    VideoCapture cap;  

    if(videoStreamUrl=="0")
    {
        std::cout <<"default camera applied"<< std::endl;
        cap.open(0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout <<"Video stream address: "<< videoStreamUrl << std::endl;
        cap.open(videoStreamUrl);
    }

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {  
        std::cout << "Couldn't open camera : " << endl;  
        return -1;  
    }
```

but when I am trying to use the rtsp url of the IP camera in docker, it is not working:

to start the docker :

```
docker run -i -t <docker image> /bin/bash
```

in the cpp code shown above

let videoStreamUrl = rtsp://name:pwd@ and 
cap.isOpened() is always false in docker image (but works in my local linux system).

may I check is there anything missing ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: enable all UDP port in docker I think then it will able to communicate.

Comment: @Adiii , thanks for the comment, for my case, I just realized that I forgot the installation of some required packages before install the opencv, as shown below:  apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libgtk-3-dev -y , after the installation, it works for the ip camera, thanks again !

Comment: perfect, make sure dependency always first :) ;)